# Getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object inside SignalR OnDisconnected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm trying to get user by username, my code is working inside the `OnConnected` method but in `OnDisconnected` i'm getting `Object reference is not set to an instance of an object` this is my code:

Working in here:

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{
    var id = Context.ConnectionId;
    var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    var connectedUser = new ChatUserModel();

    var existingUserResponse = await _client.GetAsync("chats/users/" + userName + "/");
    if (existingUserResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var existingUserResult = existingUserResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var existingUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatUserModel>(existingUserResult);
            existingUser.connectionId = id;
        connectedUser = await AddOrUpdateUser(existingUser);
    }

    var response = await _client.GetAsync("chats/users");
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatUserModel>>(result);

    Clients.Client(id).userConnected(users);
}
```

But not in here:

```
public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;

    try
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("chats/users/" + userName + "/");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
    //var existingUserResult = existingUserResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    //var existingUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatUserModel>(existingUserResult);
    //existingUser.connectionId = "";

    //var connectedUser = await AddOrUpdateUser(existingUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnDisconnect method is calling from server not from client because of that User is null.

For handling this condition you should match connectionIds with user and save somewhere and in OnDisconnect you can reach user by ConnectionId

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{
    var id = Context.ConnectionId;
    var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    SaveUserToDb(id,userName);// 
    // other codes
}

public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    var id = Context.ConnectionId;
    var userName = GetUserNameFromDB(id);

    // and now you have your username 
}
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: hi i tried that and it's working because it's local but when using web api it's not working

Comment: if it is working on local it must work on server too, there is no difference, I think you have another problem about this.